# ggplot only show positive values on y-axis (faceted plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
mpg2 <- mpg %>% mutate(hwy = hwy - 30)
 ggplot(mpg2, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   facet_grid(year ~ fl, scales = "free") + 
   scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = 2))
```

With the code chunk above I'd like to do three things simultaneously:

1. Don't display any `(-)` negative y-axis labels (in my example you'd need to delete the `-40`, `-30`, and `-60` labels). I only want zero and positive labels to show.
2. Keep `scales = "free"`
3. Keep the expanded scale as well

How do I do it?

[image: facet delete negative]

Comment: For creating labels by magnitude, i.e. absolute value, add `labels = abs` in your scale. Beyond that, I don't know what issue there is. You have scales set to free...how does this differ from what you expect?

Comment: in your `scale_y_continious` you can add `breaks =seq(0,60,10)` so that it removes the labels  - or do you just want to remove the `-` sign?

Comment: Or use `scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = 2), limits = c(0,NA))` to remove elements with negative values from view.

Comment: Or use an anonymous function as labels argument: `labels = function(x) replace(x, x < 0, "")`

Comment: I tried the solutions above and @markus comes the closest, I just don't want the tickmarks that are left behind. I updated my question with an image. The bottom plot is exactly what I'm looking for (from my image).

Comment: @JasonHunter Can you maybe elaborate on the specific use case? I'm really curious where something like this can be an effective visualisation.

Comment: @Roman when building control charts you want to see both the upper and lower control limits. They're symmetrical and the lower control limits can fall into the negative territory even if it doesn't make sense (age, height, length, etc.). As a courtesy to the viewer I may remove the negative y-axis labels, and keep the LCL as a visual cue, dependent on context. Here's a control chart if you've never seen one  https://asq.org/-/media/Images/Learn-About-Quality/control-chart.png?la=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can pass a function to the breaks argument in `scale_y_continuous` that returns a numeric vector of length two, in this case.

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
mpg2 <- mpg %>% mutate(hwy = hwy - 30)
my_breaks <- function(x) c(0, (((max(x) / 2) %/% 10) + 1) * 10)
```

The function outputs `0` and `(((max(x) / 2) %/% 10) + 1) * 10` which gives OP's desired output. The upper break is the maximum of `y` divided by `2` and 'rounded up' to the next larger multiple of `10`.

Example

```
my_breaks(67)
# [1]  0 40
```

Plot

```
ggplot(mpg2, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(year ~ fl, scales = "free") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = 2), 
                                           breaks = my_breaks)
```

[image]